# Creating Database View using ST_Buffer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql

I am trying to understand how to create a database view that shows a 150 foot buffer around each point in a table.  The table of points changes pretty frequently and I would like to use a view instead of just buffering the points and having to update the polygon layer all the time.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.1 and my SDE database is running on SQL Server 2012.

I have some experience building view layers in a PostgreSQL environment but that was a while ago and I'm struggling to get my head around doing things in this new space.

I started out reading the documentation for the '[Create Database View](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-database-view.htm)' tool but am having trouble figuring out how to put together the SQL statement.  Where do I put the `.ST_Buffer()` part of the statement?  I'm confused because `.ST_Buffer()` only accepts the distance as an argument, and it has a dot prefix, which makes me think that I need to use it as a function. I can't seem to find any references to doing this anywhere on the web.  Is it even possible to do this in the software environment I'm using?

This is the best stab I have taken:

`SELECT OBJECTID, LocationID, shape.st_buffer(47.5) FROM gisdb.DCGIS.TransformerBank`

When I run that the tool errors out and reports:

`ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
[[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot find either column "shape" or the user-defined function or aggregate "shape.st_buffer", or the name is ambiguous.]
DBMS table not found
Failed to execute (CreateDatabaseView).`

Comment: For me the first hit with "sde st_buffer" was http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java//index.htm#geodatabases/st_buffer.htm. The third hit looks better http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//006z0000003z000000

Comment: That page only references postgres and oracle - not SQL server.  If I was back in a postgres world I'd have this nailed down.  When I search for "ST_Buffer SDE SQL Server" the most relevant page is http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-buffer.htm -- But even that doesn't make it clear how to form the SQL statement in the context of the 'Create Database View' page.

Comment: I apologize. However, I thought that the idea of SDE was to make the database backends abstract. Have you tried that syntax with SQL Server? I mean `SELECT OBJECTID, LocationID, sde.st_buffer(shape, 47.5) FROM gisdb.DCGIS.TransformerBank` if "shape" is the geometry column?

Comment: The functions aren't the same.  In the postgres/oracle documentation the function accepts two arguments - the geometry and the distance.  In the SQL documentation the function only accepts ONE - distance.  That's a major part of my confusion - I don't understand how to reference the geometry in the SQL space.  That's why i tried 'shape.st_buffer(47.5)' in my example code.  (47.5 because the documentation says the function assumes the units are meters).

Comment: I do not find any SQL Server examples from your previous link.

Comment: Hence my confusion.  The buffer function clearly exists in sql server - I just don't understand how to (or if) I can use it in the manner I'd like to.  I know this is possible in other environments.  So I am asking for help understanding how to do this in ArcGIS/SQL server - or help clearing up if what I'm trying to do is even possible in my current setup.

Comment: The ST_Buffer function is a Microsoft product. It has only tangential relation to the Esri SDE.* function.  There are no Esri geometry functions for SQL-Server because the database doesn't support them. As such this question is very nearly a pure database issue.  I would recommend creating views using the native database client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error stems from the incorrect syntax for SQL Server's spatial buffer function.  SQL Server's spatial functions are case sensitive and don't use the underscore like Esri's ST_Geometry, Oracle spatial or PostGIS.  The query should look like:

`SELECT OBJECTID, LocationID, shape.STBuffer(47.5) FROM gisdb.DCGIS.TransformerBank`

I tested a similar query in the Create Database View tool in ArcGIS 10.2.1 where the tool runs successfully and the view renders in ArcMap.

[SQL Server - STBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933965.aspx)